# Usestate not updating in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have this program which renders ui after fetching data from firebase and is expected to rerender after every updates it get from database but i am getting the updates as expected and able to log the values but i am not able to update the value inside usestate. The ui gets render initially but no rerender after other updates.

my main isssue is that the ui is not rendering after initial render inspite of recieving updates

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [lobbyDetails, setLobbyDetails] = useState<LobbyDetails>({
    allowed_games: [],
    code: "",
    desc: "",
    game: "",
    host: "",
    maxPlayers: 0,
    minPlayers: 0,
    players: [],
    status: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for real-time changes in the data
    // Initialize Firebase app
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // Initialize database
    const db = getDatabase();
    // Reference to the specific location in the database
    const dbRef = ref(db, `lobbies/${lobbyId}`);
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const data = snapshot.val();
          console.log("Data is available inside if");
          console.log(data);
          resolve(data);
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
          reject(new Error("No data available"));
        }
      })
        .then((data) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setLobbyDetails((prevDetails) => ({
            ...prevDetails,
            ...data,
          }));    // this is not working      
          console.log("Data is available inside then");
          console.log(lobbyDetails); // this is not working: log the initial value of lobbyDetails but not updated value
          console.log(data); // this is working: log the updated data every time database is updated
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
  }, []);
```

help me!!

I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way you are trying to log the updated value of `lobbyDetails` immediately after calling `setLobbyDetails`. The state updates performed by `setLobbyDetails` are asynchronous, meaning that the updated value may not be immediately available right after calling `setLobbyDetails`. I have modified your code below;

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [lobbyDetails, setLobbyDetails] = useState<LobbyDetails>({
  allowed_games: [],
  code: "",
  desc: "",
  game: "",
  host: "",
  maxPlayers: 0,
  minPlayers: 0,
  players: [],
  status: "",
});

useEffect(() => {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getDatabase();
  const dbRef = ref(db, `lobbies/${lobbyId}`);
  
  const onDataChange = (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      console.log("Data is available inside onDataChange");
      console.log(data);
      setLobbyDetails((prevDetails) => ({
        ...prevDetails,
        ...data,
      }));
    } else {
      console.log("No data available");
    }
  };
  
  const onError = (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  };
  
  const dbRefSubscription = onValue(dbRef, onDataChange, onError);
  
  return () => {
    // Clean up the subscription when the component unmounts
    off(dbRef, onDataChange);
    // You might also want to handle the error case:
    // off(dbRef, onError);
  };
}, [lobbyId]); // Include 'lobbyId' as a dependency

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Updated lobbyDetails");
  console.log(lobbyDetails);
}, [lobbyDetails]); // Log lobbyDetails whenever it changes
```

I also included `[lobbyDetails]` as a dependency for `useEffect`, it will run whenever `lobbyDetails` is updated. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you but my problem is that to render the ui after every updates i recieve but the ui is not rendering after initial render

Comment: Try adding `lobbyDetails` to your useEffect dependency array. It should re-render when `lobbyDetails` is updated.

Comment: when i use lobbydetails in dependency aray it kind of goes into infinte loop like when useeffct runs it changes the lobbydetails and when lobby details changes it triggers useeffect

Comment: From a high level understanding it seems when `lobbydetails` updates and the useEffects re-renders/re-runs, the state is set again in `setLobbyDetails`, and the reference object changes which then causes the useEffect to run again, hence the infinite loop. Try installing useDeepCompareEffect and replace useEffect.

Comment: Not working i used

Answer (score 0):

This is React related, react useEffect triggers based on the deps argument

```js
// type: function useEffect(effect: EffectCallback, deps?: DependencyList): void
useEffect(()=> {
  console.log("triggered on `deps` change")
}, [deps])
```

useEffect takes two arguments, one the function to run, and the other when to trigger that function (as an array). useEffect with no deps (empty array) as you are using will only be executed when the component is rendered. In order to get a console.log() each time the lobbyDetails are updated you must pass `lobbyDetails` as deps to the useEffect.

```
// Use another useEffect to observe changes to lobbyDetails
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("LobbyDetails updated:", lobbyDetails);
}, [lobbyDetails]);
```